# circuit box problem

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

Sparks flew out of my breaker box, probably due to faulty wiring.  In an effort to troubleshoot, I removed all the breaker and labeled them.  Got a wire tracer and tried to trace the wires to see nothing was cross wired. Got a new 20amp breaker and reconnected one of the outlet that was 20amp. For test sake, I only connected one outlet.  Getting a 118.5V reading, receptacle tester is reading correct, yet the fan won't turn.

Suspecting the wires or the receptacle it self may have been damaged, I take a new 14/2 wire, about 24 inches, connect the black to 20amp breaker, white to the neutral bar of the panel and ground to the ground bar of the panel.  using a new outlet, I'm getting 118.5v reading and receptacle tester shows its correctly connected. Yet the fan won't turn.

Not sure what else to check.  Do I new a new circuit panel?  Please help.

---

The house is little over 40 years old and and the panel is just as old I'm guessing. The panel is Square D QO.

I'm a contractor and have worked with enough electricians and have basic electric skills and knowledge.

The fan was plugged in temporary for testing.  The fan is not broken because I tested the fan at my neighbor's house and it works fine there.

I guess my question is can the circuit panel itself go bad, or could it have been damaged when the sparks flew? Everything but the main feed is disconnected so it's safe for me to do wire tracing.  I haven't completed the all the tracing yet, but the ones I traced so far are not cross wired and appear correct. And, when I connect those back up with a new breaker and new outlet, get 118.5v reading, and receptacle tester is reading the wires are correct, the fan won't work.  The only conclusion I can come up with is the panel has gone bad.

I'm probably going to get a new panel anyway since the house or the panel does not have a main shut-off, and I'm not about to start checking the connection of the panel itself without shutting off the power. But I do want to avoid having to pull new wires through out the house if possible.

So I guess it's now becoming testing for future knowledge, and maybe I can post what I find here for everyone.

So, here are the facts:
- New 14/2 wire
- Black is connected to a brand new 20amp breaker
- White is in the neutral bar of the circuit panel
- ground is is the ground bar of the circuit panel
- other end of 14/2 is connected directly to one brand new outlet
- multi-meter is reading 118.5V
- receptacle tester is showing the outlet is correctly wired.
- But connecting a fan I know works, doesn't turn on.

What else can I safely test until I get the power turned off on Monday?

Comment: What make and model is your breaker box?  Also, the fan is something you're plugging into the outlet you've hooked up temporarily for troubleshooting I take it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Where are you located, and do you have any electrician experience at all? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Photos of the panel, its bus bars naked of breakers, and anything around where the unfused feed connects would be helpful.  **THE FEED IS HOT - DO NOT TOUCH IT** as it can kill you. Honestly I am a little concerned about your boldness:skill ratio, please be very careful!

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The house is little over 40 years old and and the panel is just as old I'm guessing. The panel is Square D QO. I'm a contractor and have worked with enough electricians and have basic electric skills and knowledge. The fan was plugged in temporary for testing. The fan is not broken because I tested the fan at my neighbor's house and it works fine there. I guess my question is can the circuit panel itself go bad, or could it have been damaged when the sparks flew? Everything but the main feed is disconnected so it's safe for me to do wire tracing. I haven't completed the all the

Comment: When the fan is plugged in then, you do not read 1xx.xx at all with the meter? Most likely you aren't, and that means (most likely) you have a bad connection, probably inside the panel as you suggest, the high impendance point is probably where the sparks flew. The sparks flying probably (guessing) was due to a dirty or loose connection point. Under load, you'll read 0v (or very close to it), but the current necessary to drive the fan isn't being delivered over the bad connection. (you *might* be able to see it with a thermal imager but thats a big might).

Comment: The 118.5v I'm getting is from the temporary outlet without the fan plugged in.  I'll plug in the fan and try to measure again.  However, it's not just one section of the panel.  no matter where I connect the breaker to, it's the same thing.

Comment: Understood, and what I'm suggesting still seems most likely (from knowledge of physics/electrical application). I would expect it is where the main meets the lug or the leg's connection to the bus bar - try to get the id info off the panel or photo posted of the panel. @Harper & ThreePhaseEel know their trade for sure; I've been posting here a few years and they can probably tell you precisely what to look for. Either way, to repair that(or replace the panel), you'd need to pull the meter.

Comment: Just tested the temporary outlet. Hooked up the fan in one outlet, multimeter in the second outlet. As is, it’s reading 118.5v. I plug in the fan, still 118.5v. After I turn on the fan, it drops to 0v.  How can this happen?

Comment: It is what I described above. It's a high impedance circuit. Similar to a high resistance circuit in that; when (for example), a connection burns, and electrical connectivity is 100% impacted by "whatever" (dirt, carbon, plastic, etc), you'll read a very high resistance resistance (or low voltage). However, when the same thing happens, but there is a < 100% impact (think for example a strand of hair thickness) of good electrical connectivity, you will read full voltage - until you draw current. Drawing current, will create a voltage drop on the bad connection (strand of hair).

Comment: By the way; you may have lost your neutral. I'd certainly like to see one of the answers from @ThreePhaseEel or Harper, but I'm pretty confident you are at the point you need to secure the mains (call the power company& electrician) as the connection issue could be their end they need to know. And you have a repair or replacement to make, so it is needed anyways.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It looks like you now have two separate accounts; you should [request that they be merged](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: trying to add the picture of the panel but not sure how to.

Comment: @noybman The power is getting shut off tomorrow so I can safely change out the panel. I hope that will help.  So is it suggested that the circuit panel itself may have been damaged?

Comment: Certainly possible, but at the same time I can't invision how. What size service does the panel have? For the size of a main feed.... 60Amps or more, I'd expect it to be pretty clear what "burned" out. I think you really want to not only have the electric company turn it off, but also inspect the line up to the service loop/box or farther. If you cant post a photo using the img tags, try imgur or tinypic websites and paste the links to it in your original question.

Comment: @noybman Without doing any digging, I did see a little burn mark on one of the terminals, where I think I saw the sparks.  I guess after the power is off and I remove the panel, I will be able to really dig through it.

Answer (score 5):

### Big arc flash is big

Sparks flew out **from your breaker box**.  Not from your meter pan, nor from a socket; from the breaker box.  I assume you normally keep the cover *on it* and no gaps in the cover, so sparks *getting around* the breakers is actually a pretty big deal.  **This is a *big* arc flash**.

So I would expect it to leave **big** evidence behind.  And where I would look is

- where the incoming power wires connect to the main buses (since you mentioned you don't have a main breaker -- is it a Rule of Six panel with a separate 8-12 space top area, and separate busing for the rest of the panel?)
- where the main breaker bolts down to the buses (if you have one)
- where the main neutral feed lands on the neutral bar *(**treat this as "hot"**, don't think it's safe because it's neutral)*
- Any of the branch circuit buses where branch circuit breakers clip on to the bus
- Various connections on the neutral bar generally

I would expect a scorched main lug or burnt wires where the supply wire meets the lug.

Once the power is turned off, get the correct tools and try *torquing down* each of the lug screws.  Pay very close attention to the amount of torque needed for the screw to start moving - you must do this "by feel", a click-type torque wrench is for setting torque, not measuring it.  If any lug is significantly looser than another, then *gotcha*.  Certainly do not do that with the power on; I don't know about you but all my hex sockets are made of metal :)

Then I would remove all of the wires from those lug screws, pull them back and inspect thoroughly for any sign of arcing damage.   Any damage is call for replacing the lug and nipping back the wire just enough to seat it on clean wire.  Don't fail to replace the lug unless physical inspection reveals it to be perfect.

QO is a fine, modern industrial tier panel and its quality is beyond reproach; however if a lug were improperly torqued, that would cause this.  Reapply anti-oxidation paste to the aluminum wires and reattach. If you found improper torquing before, this  should be the end of it.

If you are replacing the panel, replace with another QO so you don't have to buy all new breakers, unless there's some amazing feature of a competing panel that you *really, really* need. (Bolt-on-neutral and cheap generator interlocks are not two of them *because QO has those*).

### Buy the biggest panel you possibly can

And buy a 40/42-space panel unless it simply will not possibly fit.  The cost difference isn't that much over 20/24 space panels, and that assures you'll never ask "My panel is full. How do I add this circuit?"  That is the #1 panel related question around here, and it's so easily avoided, and right now is the time to avoid it.

Comment: But could a neutral being lost have allowed "a poor" ground to arc out (thus letting him see 120 on a meter), but not be able to carry current?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I will certainly inspect for the burn marks after I get the power turned off. I was going to buy Square D Homeline, because I was going to replace all the breakers with new ones anyway.  Figured new clean breakers with new clean panel. Maybe even pull new wires if I can tough it out in the small HOT attic space.  I've tried to compare the QO and homeline, but aside from cost, I couldn't find a review that specifically said QO is better.  It;s more of a preference. Should I go with QO?

Comment: That's called "throwing parts at a problem" - and it's a complete waste of resources. Homeline is *exactly what it says on the tin*, a line intended only for residential use, to hit the (slightly) lower price-points sought by builders buying at high volume. The euphemism is 'builder grade' but it means *cheapie*.  They [won't even sell](https://www.schneider-electric.us/en/faqs/FA175909/) Homeline to industry.

Comment: Getting rid of the old Rule of Six panel is a blessing.  What I mean @ch1234 is the chance of 20 QO breakers all being bad *without looking bad* is highly improbable. (and they don't "fail deadly"; if they did, they'd have a rep like Challenger or Zinsco.) I'd expect any QO problems to be visibly apparent either at the screw, or at the clip that grabs onto the stab.

Comment: Found the problem. One of the neutral terminal was loose. And it was next to the breaker I was working on. So when I went to flip the breaker back on, the wire must of moved enough to cause a problem. And damaged the ground cable connection as well. Tightened the neutral wire that was loose and cleaned the ground cable and re-attaches it and got things working.

Comment: Changing the panel is not an option at the moment due to cost and how long it will take to get a licensed electrician, permit etc. So I want to upgrade the sub-panel. Since it’s a 100amp service, I’m assuming I can only use a sub panel rated for 100amps right? Not 125amp? Also, if the main panel is QO, do I need to use QO subpanel or can I use Homeline subpanel life?

Comment: @ch1234 that's a new question but subpanel's ampacity must be >= the feed breaker. Even that is not necessary if it has a main breaker. You can mix and match panel types in the same house, but that means a run to the store every time you add a circuit.  If they're the same you can keep a 15 and a 20 on-hand as a spare.  Besides, why are you in love with HOM? For a 24-**space** main-lug plug-on-neutral panel, my local HD wants $57 for QO and $70 for HOM. Are you getting confused by "circuits"? Circuits is a BS marketing claim, only spaces matter.

Comment: Here's [the QO](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-QO-125-Amp-24-Space-24-Circuit-Indoor-Main-Lug-Plug-On-Neutral-Load-Center-with-Cover-Ground-Bar-QO124L125PGC/204844612) panel.  Here's [the HOM](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-125-Amp-24-Space-48-Circuit-Indoor-Main-Lug-Plug-On-Neutral-Load-Center-with-Cover-Ground-Bar-HOM2448L125PGC/204836361) panel. The HOM boasts more "circuits", but these days, that is useless, spaces is what matters.

Comment: @Harper I'm not in love with Homeline. It's just that my local homedepot only has the QO in 6 spaces only but have the homeline in 125amp 24 space.

Comment: @ch1234 I can see why. **They get more money for Homeline!**  This may be one of those deals where HD lowballs certain items while overcharges for most others. Might be worth either hitting up Lowe’s or Menards, or calling round to genuine electrical supplies...

Comment: @Harper I called around but could not find a QO with m0re than 12 spaces.  As a matter of fact, the local electrical supplier didn't even carry Square D panels.  They only had eaton and they prefered Eaton over Square D.  So, I ended up with Square D Homeline 125amp 24 spaces.  It's still a good panel.  Got it mounted today and traced some of the wires to make sure they were ok, I'm going to pull new wires so I can put the outlets and the lights for each room on it's own breaker. I'll be using 14/2 wires. Can I just use 20amp breakers or should I 20 for some and 15 for others?

Comment: @ch1234 I agree, Homeline is a perfectly safe panel.  You shouldn't have any worries about it.  One suggestion about wiring rooms is, try to have any given room have more than 1 circuit in it, so that if one room becomes the computer room or man cave, there are at least 2 circuits to support everything. My preferred way of doing that is to run circuits down walls, hitting outlets on both sides of the wall, rather than circling a room (which is a waste of wire if you think about it). Just remember some rooms require 20A breakers and those require 12AWG wire.  #14 needs 15A breakers.